# Scala: Best way to iterate over collection and populate Array

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, scala-2.8, scala-collections

scala noob here, i have a collection (Seq) of xml nodes, and i would like to populate an Array based on each node:

```
val nodes = data.child \\"package"
var packages = new Array[Package](nodes.length)
var index = 0
for(val entry <- nodes) {
   packages(index) = new Package(entry)
   index = index+1
}
```

Although  it works, does not look much "scala-ish" to me, and i'm sure there's a better way to do it..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(data.child \\ "package") map(new Package(_)) toArray
```